# How to use JiaoZiVideoPlayer to play local mp4 videos?

Tags: android, jiaozivideoplayer

I'm trying to play a local mp4 video using this player on android:

https://github.com/lipangit/JiaoZiVideoPlayer

I've managed to get it to work using the sample video url:

jzvdStd.setUp("http://jzvd.nathen.cn/c6e3dc12a1154626b3476d9bf3bd7266/6b56c5f0dc31428083757a45764763b0-5287d2089db37e62345123a1be272f8b.mp4"
                            , "饺子闭眼睛" , Jzvd.SCREEN_WINDOW_NORMAL);

However, when I change it to youtube link or a local uri link, video loading failed error is displayed:

```
    // Add video
    Uri uri = Uri.parse("android.resource://"+ getActivity().getPackageName()+"/"+R.raw.video_sample);
    JzvdStd jzvdStd = (JzvdStd) rootView.findViewById(R.id.video_player);
    jzvdStd.setUp(uri.toString()
            , "How It Works" , Jzvd.SCREEN_WINDOW_NORMAL);
```

Answer (score 2):

You may try this.

```
 String path = getApplicationContext().getFilesDir().getAbsolutePath() + "/" + videoData.getVideoPath();
 File file = new File(path);
 Uri mp4VideoUri = Uri.fromFile(file);
 try{
     JZDataSource jzDataSource = null;
     jzDataSource = new JZDataSource(mp4VideoUri);
     jzDataSource.title = "your title";
     jzvdStd.setUp(jzDataSource, JzvdStd.SCREEN_WINDOW_NORMAL);
     jzvdStd.startVideo();
}catch (Exception e){
     Log.d(TAG, e.toString());
}
```

Answer (score 0):

All the steps to use jzvd player and play mp4 on your screen.

Add the dependency

```
 implementation 'cn.jzvd:jiaozivideoplayer:7.0.5'
```

Add to your build gradle>android tag

```
  compileOptions {
    sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
}
```

Add to xml file

```
 <cn.jzvd.JzvdStd
        android:id="@+id/video_player"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />
```

Your Activity looks like

```
public class ShowVideoActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
JzvdStd jzvdStd;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
    this.getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN, WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_show_video);

    jzvdStd = (JzvdStd) findViewById(R.id.video_player);

    String videoLink = getIntent().getExtras().getString("videoLink");
    jzvdStd.setUp(videoLink, "title", 0);

    jzvdStd.setScreenFullscreen();
    jzvdStd.backButton.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    jzvdStd.batteryLevel.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    jzvdStd.batteryTimeLayout.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    jzvdStd.titleTextView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    jzvdStd.fullscreenButton.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    jzvdStd.dismissBrightnessDialog();
    jzvdStd.dismissVolumeDialog();
    jzvdStd.dissmissControlView();
    jzvdStd.dismissProgressDialog();
    jzvdStd.startVideo();

    RequestOptions requestOptions = new RequestOptions();
    requestOptions.isMemoryCacheable();
    Glide.with(jzvdStd.getContext())
            .setDefaultRequestOptions(requestOptions)
            .load(videoLink)
            .diskCacheStrategy(DiskCacheStrategy.ALL)
            .into(jzvdStd.thumbImageView);
}

@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    if (Jzvd.backPress()) {
        super.onBackPressed();
        return;
    }
    super.onBackPressed();

}

@Override
public void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();

}

@Override
protected void onPause() {
    super.onPause();
    Jzvd.releaseAllVideos();
}
```

}